# Error on running an asp.net application in localhost(through code)

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, web-applications

I have a asp.net web application ,which when i run ,i get the following error:

Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\ApplicationName\CustomGroups.xml'

1.What could be the *possible reason* causing this?
2.*How* to rectify?

Note: I dont even have Inetpub in my C:\ folder.

Comment: where did you host your application?

Comment: @siddaramesh .No where.I am running locally through code.

Comment: Enable IIS then run your application